# Sine identity involving (3/p) for prime p greater than 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am working through Ireland and Rosen's "Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" and am very stuck on this problem (#34 in Chp 5, 2nd edition):

Note that $(a/b)$ is the Legendre symbol (or Jacobi symbol, if you prefer).

"If $p$ is an odd prime distinct from $3$ show that $(3/p)=\prod\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(3-4\sin^2\frac{2\pi j}{p}).$"

I have verified the claim computationally for $p=5$ and $p=7$, and drawn some nice little plots of $5-$ and $7-$ gons in the complex plane, but this has given me no real insight that I can generalize to higher primes. I suspect I am missing some simple but esoteric trigonometric fact.

If it is not asking too much, I would strongly prefer some *hints* instead of complete answers so that I can solve it mostly on my own, and I promise to post my complete answer later when (if?) I solve it. Many thanks.

---

**UPDATE**
After many days of nonsense in which I used a double angle formula incorrectly because it was 5am, I have the following:

For a given prime $p$, let $z_k=e^{(2\pi ki)/p}$. Then, $|z_k^2-1|=2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{p}\right)$. I will post the full proof of this in my answer when I eventually get it.

I now have the original RHS as $\prod\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(3-4|z_j^2-1|^2)$. I am trying not to use advanced techniques such as those advocated in the comments. Hints on where to go from here are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given that Irland and Rosen have some **algebraic** tendency, it would be a great start considering algebraically.

Comment: The Main idea would be 1. writing the RHS in terms of root of unity $\zeta_p= \exp(2\pi i /p)$, and 2. Prove that the product on RHS except for the term $3^{(p-1)/2}$ is a multiple of $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$.

Comment: To finish the proof, it follows that 1. RHS is an integer (rational integer), and 2. As a result of product on RHS, it becomes $3^{(p-1)/2}$ plus an algebraic integer $\beta$ which is a multiple of $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$. Therefore, the $\beta$ must be a rational integer which is divisible by $p$.

Comment: @i707107 thanks very much for these hints. Initially they don't give me a 'eureka!' moment, but I am going to dig in and we'll see what happens.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the edit. I would have written it this way but I wanted to copy it exactly as in the book.

Comment: A correction on the hint: $\beta$ is divisible by $1-\zeta_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$.

Comment: @i707107 I think I am close to a solution, thanks to your hints, although perhaps not in the way you had suggested entirely. Will update as promised if I get it!

Comment: my solution involves Galois Theory and splitting of primes in cyclotomic field. I found that those concepts might not assumed in the book by Ireland and Rosen. So, probably your way will be more coherent with the order of contents in the book. I am looking forward to seeing it.

Comment: For the sake of getting my research done, I need to move on, but later in the summer I will post what I have. I have worked it into an interesting polynomial in terms of roots of unity, which I suspect will have a nice cancelling pattern to them related to whether $p\equiv_4 1$ or $3$, but it will take awhile to write it all out.